# Android app launcher for disabled apps?

Tags: android, launcher

I'd like to install lot's of apps as if it would be a web page (e.g. entering new cafe - they have an app, after couple month I have 500-600 apps easily).

I'd like to keep most of the apps disabled by default. This is easy to achieve with Titanium Backup nightly schedule + categories. I can whitelist apps that should not be auto-frozen. Same about Island (god mode) + Greenify, which is even better and user friendly.

But when an app is disabled, the launchers immediately removes the icon from the screen, while I still want to be able organize my icons the way I like, let's say if this is a cafe - may be I have a page with all eatery apps. For Island - I have to create new 'unfreeze' icon manually for every app. Or I have to navigate to Play Market and hit "Enable" there (the button that replaces "Install").

I want to keep the icon on the launcher for disabled app without extra manual work. May be plugin to the Nova Launcher? The Nova Launcher have interesting feature: if you restore backup and there is an icons but app is not installed on this device yet - it shows grayed out icon instead, and if you hit it, it starts installation. May be this feature can be used to create a plugin to keep disabled apps grayed-out? May be such plugin exists? Any ideas or advice?

Comment: Welcome Dmitry! What launcher are you using that is removing the frozen/disabled apps from the screen?  I just tested Nova Launcher for you, and I didn't have that experience.

Comment: Dmitry, AFAIK, unless you have root access on the device, even if you disable/freeze an Android app, it can unfreeze itself.  Many apps won't do this (because it's bad behavior), but many will (I'm looking at you, AccuWeather).  I have seen this problem on at least 5 different versions of Android, but I have not tested every version.

Comment: RockPaperLz, it is on Nova, but in fact it affects all Launchers 100%. How do you freezing app? There is certainly some misunderstanding, may be you are talking about killing a process? Yes, I'm certainty talking about root. Sorry, I've transferred question from the other StackOverflow and there is no Root tag here. Both methods described 
 (Island in god mode & Titanium) are only possible in root.

Comment: When I want to freeze an app, I'll generally use a tool like SuperFreezZ or Greenify.  Years ago, I used Titanium for that purpose.  I tested freezing apps on a couple non-rooted devices, and it didn't change anything in their launchers.  Your question and comment make me wonder if freezing an app on a rooted device is inherently different than doing so on a non-rooted device.

Comment: I never seen usage of "Freezing" term in non-rooted devices at all. Greenify calls it "hibernating", this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for app disablers, when app is disabled from package manager point of view or from PlayStore point of view, you have "enable" button in play store for disabled apps instead of "install". For the rest of the system it appears as completely uninstalled app, that's why icons 100% got removed. Greenify can cooperate with Island and in this case there are "deep hibernation" which is actually disabling app.

Comment: Disabling app is possible on non rooted phone only inside "work profile" sandbox. Island takes advantage of this appearing as device administrator for isolated apps with "work" profile. In rooted phone there is a God Mode for Island, when it is installed special way at the very beginning and when it can manage all apps. Yes, the way Titanium freezes is same app disabling way (it is package manager command, to disable app).

Comment: I think it is better to remove "frozen" from the question title then...

Comment: Yes, I think some app authors perhaps use the terms "disabled", "frozen", and "hibernated" a little too much as synonyms.  I edited your interesting question to simple use the term "disabled", because that fits well with Android's "Enabled/Disabled" model.

Comment: Ok, one thing - in my description about Island, I'm using "unfreeze" in purpose, because this is how it is called in Island, there is a button "Create Unfreeze & Launch Shortcut"
https://cdn.pixops.io/v1/w:auto/h:auto/q:3/https://www.jucktion.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Island-Android-Sandbox.png
And the way Island freezes in this mode is by disabling.

Comment: Yes, this is where much of the ambiguity of terms comes in.  Island uses "freeze" to describe what is more commonly called "disabled", and apps like SuperFreezZ use "freeze" to describe "hibernation".  Do the Android OS developers define any of these terms consistently?

Comment: I'm baffled how there are millions of launchers and millions of management apps like Link2SD that list frozen apps, but noone made a Launcher that also lists frozen apps